# Post in local json file :Angular 6

Tags: json, angular, typescript

This the view :

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="id">
<br/>
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="fname">
<br/>
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="lname">
<br/>
```

POST

This is my service :

```
setpost(donner): Observable<Interfaces[]>
{
return this.http.put<Interfaces[]>(this.mylink, donner);
}
```

this is my interface:

```
export interface Interfaces {
    id:number;
    fname:string;
    lname:string;
}
```

And this is my local JSON file  :

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "fname": "xxxx",
    "lname": "___"
  }
]
```

The problem that when clicking on the button to submit data to the local file an error alert appears

```
ERROR 
Object { headers: {…}, status: 404, statusText: "Not Found", url: "http://localhost:4200/assets/data/posts.json", ok: false, name: "HttpErrorResponse", message: "Http failure response for http://localhost:4200/assets/data/posts.json: 404 Not Found", error: "<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html lang=\"en\">\n<head>\n<meta charset=\"utf-8\">\n<title>Error</title>\n</head>\n<body>\n<pre>Cannot PUT /assets/data/posts.json</pre>\n</body>\n</html>\n" }
```

Comment: You cannot put to assets, you can only get from assets.